# Hamburger Icon Not showing

Tags: android, kotlin

When I use to change Hamburger Icon to Back Icon while add a new fragment it's Perfectly working. Here is my code

```
supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
supportActionBar!!.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
```

But when I press back button and close the fragment then it not change to hamburger icon

```
supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)
supportActionBar!!.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)
```

NOTE: I dont have drawer layout. I use this library: yarolegovich/SlidingRootNav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour, it won't automatically change when you are doing: 
`actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

One solution would be to handle it for yourself. Just change the icon manually

`actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.back);`

and on back pressed, change it to hamburger icon:

`actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.hamburger_icon);`

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: This portion Not working...
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.hamburger_icon);